# notifyDataSetChanged() causes NullPointerException when changing listview data which is retrieved from firebase

Tags: android, android-listview, firebase

I am trying to set a `ListView` inside my `Fragment`. I am getting data from Firebase which i set to my `ListView`. In my Firebase database I have a parent node `patients` which has child nodes like `patient1`, `patient2` etc. and every item in my `ListView` represents a single patient. My `ListView` will always have a maximum of 2 items as I am setting my list with the top two patients from Firebase database. Whenever a new patient is added or deleted I want my `listView` to get updated with new patient data. But when a new patient is added my app gets crashed.

**Logcat exception :-**

```
01-10 14:20:20.966 17863-17863/com.abc.tempapp/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 14:20:20.966 17863-17863/com.abc.tempapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

**Code :-**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       ...
       setListView();
       ...
    }

 public void setListView()
    {
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
        firebaseData = new Firebase("https://xyz.firebaseio.com");
        firebaseData.child("patients").orderByChild("appointment-id").limitToFirst(2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                patientList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot tempSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        int tempId = Integer.parseInt(tempSnapshot.child("appointment-id").getValue().toString());
                    String tempContact = tempSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString();
                    String tempName = tempSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    long tempTime = Long.parseLong(tempSnapshot.child("arrival-time").getValue().toString());
                    Patient patient = new Patient(tempId, tempContact, tempName, epochToDate(tempTime));
                    patientList.add(patient);
                }
                if (myAdapter == null) {
                    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, patientList);
                    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    firebaseData.child("patients").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            dataChanged();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            dataChanged();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
        });
    }

 synchronized public void  dataChanged()
    {
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
        firebaseData = new Firebase("https://xyz.firebaseio.com");
        firebaseData.child("patients").orderByChild("appointment-id").limitToFirst(2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                patientList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot tempSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            int tempId = Integer.parseInt(tempSnapshot.child("appointment-id").getValue().toString());
                            String tempContact = tempSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString();
                            String tempName = tempSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            long tempTime = Long.parseLong(tempSnapshot.child("arrival-time").getValue().toString());
                            Patient patient = new Patient(tempId, tempContact, tempName, epochToDate(tempTime));
                            patientList.add(patient);
                    }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
        });

    }
```

I don't know what I am missing here. It might be a very fundamental thing that I have got wrong, hope someone corrects me.

Comment: Debug your code and check your patientList is returned as null. \

Comment: patientList is not becoming null anywhere although patientList might be empty sometimes ,in that case there won't be anything in the list.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference 
you are reffering to an object which is null check your object 1st if its not null then implement your logic in it like  'if(object != null){
do something here}'

Comment: Ok i'll first check which object references of mine are reffering to null and then i'll apply the logic test suggested by you.

Comment: You're loading data from 3 different Firebase locations. It's not feasible for us to reproduce your problem without also having the same data structure. Instead, reduce your question to the minimum amount of code (and JSON data) that is needed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to do this and why it is helpful.

Comment: I got the solution. The problem was indeed caused by one of the above mentioned values getting nullified. The reason was the way in which I was saving data to firebase. I had used `setValue()` instead of `updateChildren()` because of which my `patients` node was getting deleted for a split second as `setValue()` method deletes the entire path and rewrite the path again with updated data. And as `patients` node was missing for that split second it was giving me `NullPointerException`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you have sort out your issue post your solution here so If any having such issue or misconception regarding saving/retrieving values

Answer (score 2):

The error message says: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference"

You have `toString()` calls in your code where you extract the data from Firebase:

```
int tempId = Integer.parseInt(tempSnapshot.child("appointment-id").getValue().toString());
String tempContact = tempSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString();
String tempName = tempSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
long tempTime = Long.parseLong(tempSnapshot.child("arrival-time").getValue().toString());
```

One of the values you receive is apparently `null` so `toString()` fails on it. This might be caused by a missing value or by your incorrect assumption about the shape of the results - try logging the contents of `tempSnapshot` or set a breakpoint there and look at the object from the debugger.

If the nulls are caused by data that is usually there but sometimes missing, you can switch from primitive types to reference types, i.e. use Integer instead of int and Long instead of long. Then you can store nulls in those fields but you will have to handle the possibility of them being null in the rest of your program.

Another possibility is to use some default value if the incoming value is null.

Also, as stated in the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html), `getValue()` returns a parsed object, e.g. Long if the data is a whole number, so we can use it to avoid parsing which is a bit slow, and just convert from Long to Integer.

Example:

```
Object tempIdObj = tempSnapshot.child("appointment-id").getValue();
Integer tempId = tempIdObj instanceof Long ? ((Long) tempIdObj).intValue() : null;
```

This code will also set tempId to null if the `appointment-id` contains a non-integer value such as `xyz` or `234.0`.

Comment: I got the solution. The problem was indeed caused by one of the above mentioned values getting nullified. The reason was the way in which I was saving data to firebase. I had used `setValue()` instead of `updateChildren()` because of which my `patients` node was getting deleted for a split second as `setValue()` method deletes the entire path and rewrite the path again with updated data. And as `patients` node was missing for that split second it was giving me `NullPointerException`. Thank you anyway.